# How to change the Google Play account in Pokemon Go to use the balance?

Tags: pokemon-go, google-play-games

I am playing Pokemon Go using Google Account 1. I then redeemed my Google Play gift card to the same account.

Then, when I try to go to the Pokemon Go shop, hoping to use the balance in Google Play account to buy coins, Pokemon Go shows the Google Play store page again, but with another Google Account 2.

This is the default account set in my Android mobile phone. How can I switch the account back to Account 1 in Pokemon Go, so that I can use the balance inside the Google Play Account 1?

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer elsewhere. You need to uninstall the app on your phone and install it using the correct account FROM THE PLAY WEB STORE. On your computer. After I did that I had the correct account when I made purchases from the Pokemon Go shop.

I didn't have to remove any of the other accounts on the phone. I am using a different account to pay for purchases than I am for playing pokemon go.

Answer (score 4):

I found a rather stupid solution -- remove all other Google accounts except account 1, i.e. the one used for playing Pokemon Go. Hope to see a better solution.

Comment: I've had this issue before. What you did really does seem to be the best solution. For some reason Google acts like people will only have one email account and will use it for the rest of their lives, so having multiple accounts tend to interfere with each other in weird ways.

Comment: I had to remove all accounts and then re-add the account with the balance to get this to work. The whole system is a little wonky.

Comment: I can't do this because I accidentally applied my Google Play credit to a work email address, and they have google pay for it disabled

Answer (score 2):

It's a stupid workaround but this works. I play for my mom and myself so I have two accounts on the phone.

You need to uninstall the game and before reinstalling, make sure you are using the account your trying to redeem your credits or gift cards on in the Google play store.
Select the proper account in Google play store then reinstall Pokemon using the right account.
Then sign in to Pokemon using the right account and it should be on the right account when you shop now.

I do it all the time, it just sucks having to constantly uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

After trying every fix I could find, I set up my Pokemon account on a discarded phone, using only that account's gmail on the phone.  When I opened the game, my credit finally appeared.